# jQuery Tooltip: Inserting HTML code with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I've got tooltips working in my WordPress posts like this one (http://vps46331.inmotionhosting.com/~hellod8/10-fun-things-to-do-with-kids-this-weekend-2-15-19-2-17-19/) down at the bottom of the page at the Share link. However, I also want to incorporate HTML into the code and that's where I'm striking out.

I found this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AK7pv/111/

But adding this to the title of my link screws everything up and it just spits out HTML in the tooltip:

```
<p>Share <button id="trigger" class="trigger" data-html="true" data-tooltip-id="1" title="<p><a href='#' title='Email'><i class='fas fa-envelope'></i> Email</a><br><a href='#' title='Copy Link'><i class='fas fa-link'></i> Copy Link</a></p>"><i class="fas fa-share"></i></button></p>
```

This is the current Javascript:

```
jQuery(function () {
    //show
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.trigger', function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass("on");
        jQuery(this).tooltip({
            items: '.trigger.on',
                position: {
                    my: "right+10 center",
                    at: "left center",
                    collision: "flip"
            }
        });
        jQuery(this).trigger('mouseenter');
    });
    //hide
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.trigger.on', function () {
        jQuery(this).tooltip('close');
        jQuery(this).removeClass("on");
    });
    //prevent mouseout and other related events from firing their handlers
    jQuery(".trigger").on('mouseout', function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your opening `<button>` tag is not closed. Also you might need `data-html=true` within the button markup.

Comment: Well, the good news is I got the button closed. The bad news is even after adding data-html=true, I just get HTML code there.

Comment: Your code works fine [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeyx2fz5/1/). There must be another Problem.